# How do I console.log json information?

Tags: javascript, json, steam, steam-web-api

quite new to working with both api's and javascript. I'm trying to console.log out the amount of times a friend of mine has died in rust, but all items are named "name:" An img of what I mean:

[image]

I'm using axios to call the api, here's the code:

```
var statsApi = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?';
var statsAppId = 'appid='+252490+'&'
var statsSteamApiKey = 'key='+process.env.STEAM_API+'&';
var statsUserArg = 'steamid='+userID; 
                
var steamStatsApi = statsApi + statsAppId + statsSteamApiKey + statsUserArg;

axios
  .get(steamStatsApi)
  .then((res) =>{
      message.channel.send("AAAA");
      // console.log(res['data']['playerstats']['stats']['name' == 'deaths']);
      for(re in res['data']['playerstats']['stats']) {
          if(re['name'] === 'deaths') {
              console.log('test');
              console.log(re['value']);
          }
          else {
              console.log('Fel');
          }
      }
  })
.catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error:', err);
})
```

Again if anyone knows how to get the amount of 'deaths' I'd be super grateful.

Comment: Can you please paste the full server response? The whole JSON object? We can't really help with screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was quite easy, if anyone has this problem just use the following code which I am about to provide:

```
var index = -1;
for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(res['data']['playerstats']['stats']).length; i++) {
   if(res['data']['playerstats']['stats'][i]['name'] === 'deaths') {
      index = i;
      var userDeaths = res['data']['playerstats']['stats'][index]['value'];
      break;
   }
}
```

What this does is that it loops trough every object named "name:" until it finds 'deaths' in one of them. I change i to that and now i'm able to print out the value which i'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Please check this code:

```
let res = [{ name: "deaths", value: 2694}, {name:"bullet_fired", value: 343328}];
let i = 0;

for(i=0;i<res.length;i++){ 
      if(res[i].name =="deaths"){ 
       console.log(res[i].value); 
      }
}
```

Here res variable will contain your json values.